# org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended

Tags: spring, jboss, wildfly, ejb-3.0, spring-4

We are trying to deploy EAR(EJB3 component and web module) in Wildfly-17 server.
The EJB3 components are injected to controllers with the help of Spring dependency injection. 
During the server startup I'm getting EJBComponentUnavailableException.

If I deploy the EJB3 and remove web module Spring dependency injection, we are able to deploy it successfully. And also able to access the bean from my Main program.

The problem happens only with Spring EJB3 dependency injection during the server startup.

We are using Wildfly10 to deploy our application. We are trying to upgrade this to Wildfly17. We are facing this issue only with the Wildfly17.

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup earname/utilsmodule/LoggerBean!com.utils.ejb.LoggerRemote [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:159)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport.handleLookup(RemoteServerTransport.java:185)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport$1.handleMessage(RemoteServerTransport.java:106)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.lambda$handleMessageData$3(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:430)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:975)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor$2$1.getReference(EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:253)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:143)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor$2$1.getReference(EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:245)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by setting lazy-init property to spring bean.

```
<bean id="testB" class="com.concretepage.B" lazy-init="true"/>
```

[Spring bean lazy-init](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/target/LazyInitTargetSource.html)